# mini210 socket multithread

Tags: c#, sockets, embedded, windows-ce, multitasking

i do have an embedded board (mini/tiny 210) 
and i did try building an application which uses **system.socket** and **system.socket.ne**t in C# ( vs2005 - **wince5 device application** but i do have **wince 6** on my device!! )

my purpose is to send and receive data bytes using Ethernet. for sending , well there is no problem but receive does need multitasking.

i should start a task so it can listen to the port if there is any data upcoming but once i add thread part to my code the whole program crashes (dose not do that in pc x64 core i5) but in embedded board it will crash.

if i eliminate multi tasking i might lose some data when **networkstream.read** is not online or when **networkstream.read** is online and i'm waiting for data,which ends in program will not respond up until the timeout. here is some of my codes . hope it helps.

this code does work :

```
private void button_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Thread TH = new Thread(new ThreadStart(con));
            //TH.Start();
            con();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("THREAD ERROR");
        }
    }
    public void con()
    {
        try
        {
            cli = null;
            cli = new TcpClient();
            cli.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(textBox_ip.Text),Convert.ToInt32(textBox_port.Text));
            st = null;
            st = cli.GetStream();
            button_connect.Enabled = false;
            button_Close.Enabled = false;
            button_disconnect.Enabled = true;
            statusBar1.Text = "Connected to server";
            //Thread rec = new Thread(new ThreadStart(recf));
            //rec.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection faild","Error");
            statusBar1.Text = "Faild to connect to server";
        }
```

this code dose **not** work :

```
private void button_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread TH = new Thread(new ThreadStart(con));
            TH.Start();
            //con();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("THREAD ERROR");
        }
    }
    public void con()
    {
        try
        {
            cli = null;
            cli = new TcpClient();
            cli.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(textBox_ip.Text),Convert.ToInt32(textBox_port.Text));
            st = null;
            st = cli.GetStream();
            button_connect.Enabled = false;
            button_Close.Enabled = false;
            button_disconnect.Enabled = true;
            statusBar1.Text = "Connected to server";
            //Thread rec = new Thread(new ThreadStart(recf));
            //rec.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection faild","Error");
            statusBar1.Text = "Faild to connect to server";
        }
    }
```

as you can see i'm getting this crash while just one of my task is in the code the second task has been commented

i appreciate your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

The crash is probably caused by updating UI elements from a secondary thread.

The `con` method reads a textbox and updates several buttons as well as a status bar, and this should only happen on the main application thread.

To verify whether this is the issue, you could simply comment out the lines in the `con` method that access UI elements (copy the textbox value to a member string before starting the thread, or just hard-code the IP address) and re-run the application.

Then to actually fix the problem you'll have to look into [Control.Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).